# Cut column from multiple files with the same name in different directories and paste into one

Tags: awk, paste

I have multiple files with the same name (3pGtoA_freq.txt), but all located in different directories.
Each file looks like this:

```
pos 5pG>A
1   0.162421557770395
2   0.0989643268124281
3   0.0804131316857248
4   0.0616563298066399
5   0.0577551761714493
6   0.0582450832072617
7   0.0393129770992366
8   0.037037037037037
9   0.0301016419077404
10  0.0327510917030568
11  0.0301598837209302
12  0.0309050772626932
13  0.0262089331856774
14  0.0254612546125461
15  0.0226130653266332
16  0.0206971677559913
17  0.0181280059193489
18  0.0243993993993994
19  0.0181347150259067
20  0.0224429727740986
21  0.0175690211545357
22  0.0183916336098089
23  0.0196078431372549
24  0.0187983781791375
25  0.0173192771084337
```

I want to cut column 2 from each file and paste column by column in one file

I tried running:

```
for s in results_Sample_*_hg19/results_MapDamage_Sample_*/results_Sample_*_bwa_LongSeed_sorted_hg19_noPCR/3pGtoA_freq.txt; do awk '{print $2}' $s >> /home/users/istolarek/aDNA/3pGtoA_all; done
```

but it's not pasting the columns next to each other.

Also I wanted to name each column by the '*', which is the only string that changes in path.

Any help with that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for i in $(find you_file_dir -name 3pGtoA_freq.txt);do awk '{print $2>>"NewFile"}' $i; done

Answer (score 0):

I would do this by processing all files in parallel in awk:

```
awk 'BEGIN{printf "pos ";
           for(i=1;i<ARGC;++i)
             printf "%-19s",gensub("^results_Sample_","",1,gensub("_hg19.*","",1,ARGV[i]));
           printf "\n";
           while(getline<ARGV[1]){
             printf "%-4s%-19s",$1,$2;
             for(i=2;i<ARGC;++i){
               getline<ARGV[i];
               printf "%-19s",$2}
             printf "\n"}}{exit}' \
results_Sample_*_hg19/results_MapDamage_Sample_*/results_Sample_*_bwa_LongSeed_sorted_hg19_noPCR/3pGtoA_freq.txt
```

If your awk doesn't have `gensub` (I'm using cygwin), you can remove the first four lines (printf-printf); headers won't be printed in that case.